# TextField's Delegate in other ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, uitextfield

I have a textField in a subview which I have subclassed. Now I want to call the textField's delegate methods in my originally view.

I tried it with this code, but somehow the methods are not called:

```
NewImageViewController *ni = [[NewImageViewController alloc] init];
textField.delegate = ni;
```

"NewImageViewController" is my origin view.

**EDIT:**

My Subclass.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol SubviewProtocol<NSObject>
- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)inTextField;
- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)inTextField;
@end

@interface PopOverViewController : UIViewController <FPPopoverControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *textField;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<SubviewProtocol> delegate;

@end
```

viewDidLoad in Subview.m :

```
textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 170, 30)];
    textField.placeholder = @"Example";
    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    textField.alpha = 0.9;
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
    textField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor]CGColor];
    textField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    textField.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:textField];
```

delegate methods in NewImageViewController.m :

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSLog(@"asd");
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSLog(@"fgh");
}
```

Comment: I think we'll need a little more code. There can be many reasons. Did you hook up the IBOutlets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since u are making UITextField as property in your subview

just do like this

i am posting the sample code that is similar to your case 
hope it helps u just go through this it may help u

```
 #import "SubView.h"
 @implementation SubView
 @synthesize aTextField;

 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
 {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    UITextField *atextField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    self.aTextField = atextField;
    [self addSubview:atextField];
    [atextField release];

  }
 return self;
}

   -(void)dealloc{
    [self.aTextField release];
    [super dealloc];
   }

 //i am setting the frame hear 
 -(void)layoutSubviews
   {
      self.aTextField.frame = CGRectMake(20,30, 100, 45);


   }

  @end


   // in your main view

   #import "ViewController.h"
   #import "SubView.h"

   @interface ViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate> // add this

   @end

   @implementation ViewController

   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
     [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //see below lines carfully
      SubView *subView = [[SubView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

   subView.aTextField.delegate = self; // you need do this
   subView.aTextField.placeholder = @"type hear";
   subView.aTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

   [self.view addSubview:subView];

   }

   - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
   {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }  

     //check out in main view
  -(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)inTextField
    {
          NSLog(@"textField end editing");
    }
     - (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)inTextField
      {
          NSLog(@"textField begin editing");
      }


   @end
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the delegate in the origin view, you can implement the delegate methods in the subview in which the textField is located.

You can implement a protocol for your subview like the following:

In the file YourSubview.h

```
@protocol YourSubviewProtocol<NSObject>
- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)inTextField;
- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)inTextField;
@end
@interface YourSubview
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<YourSubviewProtocol> delegate;
//properties and methods

@end
```

In the implementation file, i.e. YourSubview.m, you will have to call these delegate methods from inside the TextField delegate methods, something like this

```
[[self delegate] textFieldDidBeginEditing:textField];
```

In the file NewImageViewController.h

```
@interface NewImageViewController<YourSubviewProtocol>

//properties and methods

@end
```

In the file NewImageViewController.m, you will have to implement the delegate methods:

```
- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)inTextField;
{
  //do the operation
}
- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)inTextField;
{
  //do the operation
}
```

Hope this helps, all the best! :)

Comment: Hm, doesnt work for me i edit my question above with some more code.

Comment: @Sebastian I think you will have to do this in the .h file 

PopOverViewController : UIViewController <FPPopoverControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>

Maybe you have not included this line, because of which we are getting this issue.

Comment: @Sebastian Have you included both the delegate methods in the PopOverViewController.m file? Since the textField instance is a property of this class, you will have to implement both the delegate methods in this file. I see that you have included them in the NewImageViewController.m, but they have to first be included in PopOverViewController.m. Just wanted to confirm from your side...

Comment: Yes, i included them like this:
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(textFieldDidBeginEditing:)];
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(textFieldDidEndEditing:)];
}

Comment: @Sebastian Please look at the edited answer, we should be calling 

[[self delegate] textFieldDidBeginEditing:textField];

we should not be calling respondsToSelector, it was a mistake on my part, I have edited it in the answer.

Comment: Still don't get an Log when type into the keyboard.

Comment: @Sebastian In the NewImageViewController.h, you should instantiate an object of PopOverViewController like the following: 

PopOverViewController *popoverVC = [[PopOverViewController alloc] init];

popoverVC.delegate = self;

and in the NewImageViewController.h, you will have to include your protocol

NewImageViewController<SubviewProtocol>

Comment: How do I instantiate an Object in the header file ?

Comment: @Sebastian Hey, sorry, it was a typo, please do that in the NewImageViewController.m file where you have done it earlier.